# Erro quando tento abrir uma nova activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

Bom, eu tenho a `MainActivity` que tem dois botões, estou tentando fazer algo simples: Quando clicar em um, ir para uma `Activity`, quando clicar em outro, ir pra outra `Activity`.

Essa é a MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void changeActivity(View view){
            Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeSpanishActivity.class);
            startActivity(it);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

            public PlaceholderFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                    return rootView;

            }
    }
}
```

## MainActivity.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOptionIngles"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ingles"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtWelcome"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtWelcome"
    android:onClick="changeActivity"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOptionEspanhol"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Espanhol"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnOptionIngles"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtWelcome"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtWelcome"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnOptionIngles"
    android:onClick="changeActivity"/>
```

## Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.edsonmarcelo.tapfun" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- Splash screen -->
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeEnglishAcitivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home_english_acitivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeSpanishActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home_spanish" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

ERRO:

```
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable      to start activity             ComponentInfo{com.example.edsonmarcelo.tapfun/com.example.edsonmarcelo.tapfun.Home   SpanishActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at com.example.edsonmarcelo.tapfun.HomeSpanishActivity.onCreate(HomeSpanishActivity.java:21)
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
04-26 21:52:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
```

EnglisHomeActivity

```
package com.example.edsonmarcelo.tapfun;

public class HomeEnglishAcitivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_english_acitivity);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gdViewHomeEnglish);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeEnglishAcitivity.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_english_acitivity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

SpanishHomeActivity

```
package com.example.edsonmarcelo.tapfun;


public class HomeSpanishActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_spanish);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gdViewHomeEnglish);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeSpanishActivity.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_spanish, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, você não especificou qual o erro, mas o que parece estar acontecendo é abrindo somente a **HomeSpanishActivity** e nunca a outra, já que você está utilizando o mesmo método `changeActivity`.

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma, alterando este método:

```
public void changeActivity(View view) {
    Intent it;

    if (view.getId() == R.id.btnOptionIngles) {
        it = new Intent(this, HomeEnglishAcitivity.class);
    } else {
        it = new Intent(this, HomeSpanishActivity.class);
    }

    startActivity(it);
}
```

Assim você vai verificar qual botão foi pressionado e selecionar a `Activity` correta.

Comment: Fiz esta alteração porem o aplicativo abre e quando eu clico em algum dos botões, ele fecha. Alguns erros abaixo: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.edsonmarcelo.tapfun/com.example.edsonmarcelo.tapfun.HomeSpanishActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Adicionei os erros na pergunta

Comment: O erro então está na Activity aberta, na linha 21. Adicione o código dela também.

Comment: Paulo, adicionei na pergunta o codigo das duas Activity.

Comment: Resolvido! O problema era que eu tinha uma textview dentro de uma gridview. Obrigado mesmo assim Paulo Rodrigues.